# Is there a way to by-pass username and password after first login for Mosquitto broker?

Tags: client, mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

I'm a beginner in MQTT and I currently use Eclipse Mosquitto 2.0.13 for managing message routing process. I am able to create a server, set passwords for users, access from a remote computer and manage the messages. However, what I try to do and fail is to set some sort of privilege to a certain computer/client and let it by-pass the password after first time. I want another software to output/publish messages but it fails all the time since I set password for the broker and the software does not automatically enter the username and password.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is fairly low on details and I think you need to consider how Mosquitto could identify a client that has previously connected.  It could use the IP of the client (but this unlikely to be secure and IPs may change); alternatively some identifying info will need to be sent (whether its a username/password, a token, a certificate, a device serial number etc). I don't think its possible to answer your question without more info (and the "best way" is likely to be opinion based so [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: There correct solution is to fix the client that currently doesn't support username/password. Anything else would just be insecure

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.